# Why is kotlin timeout not working as it should be

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have been trying to create a decorator for a lambda function in Kotlin. The requirements for the decorator are following:

- The decorator must be able to REPEAT the process passed in the form of lambda function
- The decorator must be able to TIMEOUT after a certain time which will be passed along in the decorator.

This is what I have been able to come up so far:

```
inline fun <T, R> testDecorator(input: T,
                                timesToRepeat: Int,
                                timeout: Long,
                                crossinline work: (T) -> R): R {
    repeat(timesToRepeat - 1) {
        try {
            return runBlocking {
                  withTimeout(timeout) {
                      work(input)
        }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            // Deal with exception
        }
    }
    return work(input)
}
```

Right now, the `work` function will only be making a http request but later on I plan to add some more work.

Sample work:

```
fun sampleWork() {
val client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder() .uri(URI.create("some url")) .build(); 
val response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()); 
// Parse respone
return parsedResponse;
}
```

The problem is that the timeout is not working as expected and the function only ends after all the processes in the lambda have ended. Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: Could you share the code that you pass as `work`?

Comment: Probably, because your `work` function is not cancellable, read this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html

Comment: @broot For now there's not much in the work except making a HTTP request so I can just make use of the timeout in the http client. But, there are other use cases where in I need to be doing some extra work. I have updated the question to include sample work.

Comment: As @IR42 said, the code has to cooperate when cancelling. You use Java HTTP which doesn't at all support coroutines, so it just ignores cancellation requests. Moreover, `send()` is a blocking method which you should generally try to avoid. Use `sendAsync()` instead or better, use a http client with support for coroutines, like e.g. `ktor-client`.

Comment: That answers a lot of questions that I had. Thanks :)